Internet works after rebooting, periodically stops and starts working
I have installed postmarket OS on my old chromebook on an SD card. Every time I restart or resume my laptop (as in, close its lid for a bit and then open it again), the internet connection works, but after a while it stops working completely. I can't ping google.com (ping: bad address 'google.com') or its IP address. The entire time it seems to be connected to the wifi, but not to the internet.
I have checked for IP conflicts by noting its IP with ifconfig -a when it is connected to the network, waiting until it stops being connected to the network and then pinging that same IP address. It can not find that IP address (icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable)
I know the hardware works because internet connection works under chromeOS.

Did you ping the chromebook's IP address from the chromebook itself, or from some other computer? If you are using NetworkManager, what do nmcli g and nmcli d indicate when the network has stopped working?

I pinged it from a different computer. I am using network manager. nmcli g says connected full enabled enabled missing enabled. nmcli d says
mlan0     wifi      connected     wifiname
lo            loopback     connected (externally) lo
p2p-dev-mlan0    wifi-p2p   disconnected    ---```

You mean your internet connection, or perhaps even your network connection periodically stops working etc. Rebooting the whole Internet would sound an interesting idea, but I'd expect that's something that never happens. It likely also runs on stuff like Junos and duct tape, rather than under chromeOS.

Yes I mean my internet connection sorry, english is not my native languages
